# Is it proper use of jsp/html/javascript to make decison/logic?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have jsp page that gets value from attributes:

```
<% String blabla = request.getAttribute("blabla"); %>
```

And on the bottom of page I put js file, and after that I have logic that decide whether to show some blocks(divs) on the page based on the value of the attribute:

```
<% if("".equalsIgnoreCase(blabla)){ %>
<script type="text"/javascript>
    document.getElementById("no_blahblah_div").style.display = "block"; 
</script>
<%} else { %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("blahblah_div").style.display = "block";
</script>
<% } %>
```

And html block:

```
<div id="no_blah_blah" style="display:none"> There is no blahblah, lets go back home</div>
<div id="blahblah" style="display:none">There is blahblah, lets party!</div>
```

So I am not sure if it is correct way of doing decision/logic to display content of the page. Does it have flaws? For example, can user get content of the other divs even if they are marked as display:none? Do we have better option than this? What professionals prefer to use at similar scenarios? I would like to hear all the disadvantages(if there is any) that I might have if I use this approach. Whether it is related to processing speed, security and/or other things. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps `<div id="blablaornot"><c:out value="${"".equalsIgnoreCase(blabla)? 'There is no blahblah, lets go back home':'There is blahblah, lets party!'}" /></div>`

Comment: Couldn't you just put the messages into the if/else statements instead of putting Javascript in that shows the corresponding messages? (Disclaimer: I don't know JSP)

Comment: @Feathercrown i used text messages here as an example, I will need to display multiple blocks with many links/contents in them so I thought it is easier for me to create separate divs and put contents there and display them based on attribute value. And I am not sure when you say "just put messages into if/else statements", do you mean use print.out to display those messages?

Comment: @mplungjan Ihm, I can use tags but I think it would not help me with displaying multiple parts in the page as on each div i need to put checker as you did, I think it is better to have single script tag and put logic there that decide which divs needs to be shown.

Comment: How about `<% if("".equalsIgnoreCase(blabla)){ %><style> .divToHideOrShow { display:none}</style> <% }%>`

Comment: @Zhaiyk I meant instead of the script tags, put the div tags in the <% if/else %> things, but if you're showing/displaying multiple things, then your approach would be better anyways.